# Dell Inspiron 1525 running Windows 8.1 not detecting Wi-Fi . Can connect with Ethernet cable

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, windows-8.1

I am using a [Dell Inspiron 1525](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/servicetag/hvn9pf1/configuration) laptop and I had upgraded to Windows 8.1 Pro some 2 months back. I used Windows 7 prior to that. I had installed updates like last month. After that I had disabled updates.

Last night there was a connectivity problem for some time. I restarted my router—a Comcast/infinity router—and then was still not able to connect via Wi-Fi. I fiddled around a bit and disabled my Wi-Fi connection. Actually wanted to disable and enable. After disabling I am not able to see any Wi-Fi connections. Earlier I used to get a list of available connections.

1. Wi-Fi connection not detected. **Can connect with wire. Works fine.**
2. Airplane mode disabled.
3. No software updates for last 10 days or so.

Also my laptop is never under sleep. I normally restart often. Never put to sleep or idle mode.

Comment: i suggest you to post your Laptop model, you only provide us the Serie, there are a lot of Dell Inspiron model arround the world ;)

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question, but did you enable your wi-fi again after disabling it?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple.

As the following Dell Support article shows, your product **does not** officially support anything except `Windows XP` and `Windows Vista`.

[image]

That does not mean your system cannot run a different operating system, but there is a possibility, that device **compatibility** problems might exist on those alternative operating systems.

Quoted Text from Support Dell.

> Note regarding operating systems not listed above: 
>   Dell may not support an operating system for various reasons, including
>   discontinued support from the software vendor or lack of availability
>   with certain products.